# Qt 5.1 Visual Studio 2010 debug error from module 5.0.2

Tags: c++, qt

i´m some kind of newbe when using Qt with Visual Studio i rather like the QtCreator. Somehow, i´m involved in a c++ project where I need it now. I got the project successsfully compiled with VS 2010 & Qt version 5.0.2 but since Qt 5.1.0 I get a strange debug error when Visual Studio tries to start the appplication after compilation. The picture of the error is [attached here](http://uploadingit.com/file/0jhtrscd2ryuhrqz/QTError.png). I read that Qt projects now need the "platforms" folder inside the Qt app and I allready moved it there but still with no luck.

Actually I got Qt 5.1.1 and its the same mess but I need the 5.1.x framework because they added the windowcontainer in it. What I think is strange is that the error seems to come from a 5.0.2 module but i removed Qt 5.0.2 completely (at least I thought so). I allready changed the projects Qt version to the actual one, changed my Qts environment variables and checked the paths to the external libs. When installing Qt 5.0.2 again and changing the project to it all works fine again. There seems to be something I missed - has anyone a hint or something for me?

Comment: This probably isn't it, but just in case, have you tried doing a full rebuild of your app?

Answer (score 0):

oh no, i checked the files inside the project folder again today and gonna missed to replace an old Qt dll with a new one ... *knocking my head on the table* ... that solved the problem immediately
but much thx for your answer :)